# Options and suggestions for hyperref font?

Tags: hyperref, formatting, color

### Background

I am interested in finding and implementing a more aesthetically pleasing style for the hyperlinks in my document.

I have read through the documentation, but I find both the colored text and the colored boxes to be distracting, particularly when there are many in a page. The "french style" monospace is not distinct enough from the `\verb+font+` that I use frequently.

### Questions

1. How can I make `hyperref` links in a specific font or font style?
2. What is a pleasing way to indicate references in a document without using too many colors?

Comment: To anyone looking for an answer to Q1 (setting the style for links), the accepted answer here doesn’t answer it, but http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/how-to-style-text-in-hyperref-url re-asks it and has good answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would not change the font for the hyperlinks if the document is supposed to be printed. This will make the links stand out even though they have no function in a paper version of your document.

I would suggest using

```
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}
```

This will make the links colored in the electronic version where it serves a purpose but they will print in black. Use a color from the document color scheme.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Now that I have played around with some colors, the document doesn't look so bad.

Comment: @Martin Heller Just keep in mind that using the **ocgcolorlinks** option with the _hyperref_ package doesn't wraps long URLs as by using the **colorlinks** option!

Comment: @sokai Please don't misuse the answer space just for posting comments. I converted the non-answer to a comment to Martin's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't really satisfied with the `ocgcolorlinks` option for the `hyperref` package, I think the colors don't go well together.

For a fully configurable hyperlinks, you should use the `xcolor` package with some option in order to have 64 colors that are listed in its documentation.

You can then customize the `hyperref` package with your desires, like in this example :

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=NavyBlue,citecolor=Fuchsia]{hyperref}
```

The links will still appear black when the document is printed, but will appear with the colors you chose in a pdf Viewer.

Hope that helps.