# How to style text in hyperref \url?

Tags: hyperref, formatting, urls

I want to set color, font and similar style attributes for the text in a `\url` from the `hyperref` package. How do I go about doing it? All I have found are [comments saying that I probably don't want to do that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15834/options-and-suggestions-for-hyperref-font/15861#15861). I want to because I am using ttf fonts for my texts and I want my urls to be in that ttf and not the default (typewriter font?) that the `hyperref` package gives me. I started with just trying to get it in italics but didn't even succeed with that:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Lala \url{\itshape www.example.com}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Figure showing it not working]

I am guessing there is some hook or something but I just can't find it. Maybe I have gone blind?

Comment: Related Question: [How to get \url{} and \href{} displayed identically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202128/how-to-get-url-and-href-displayed-identically).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Internally `\url` uses `\UrlFont`. You can change it with `\urlstyle` (see the documentation of `url` in `url.sty`) or by redefining `\UrlFont`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}


\begin{document}
Lala \url{www.example.com}.

\urlstyle{sf}
Lala \url{www.example.com}.

\renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{red}\rmfamily\itshape}
Lala \url{www.example.com}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The package option `urlcolor` in the package `hyperref` does the same thing, i.e. `\usepackage[urlcolor=red]{hyperref}`.

Comment: You can simply use \urlstyle{rm}.

Answer (score 45):

Use `\href` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{http://www.example.com}{\textit{www.example.com}}.
\end{document}
```

This takes two arguments: the first is the actual url, the second is the link text.  The above code produces

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Also, it seems to not change the font into that typewriter one but keeps happily running with my ttf font. :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I wanted to provide link colored in blue and to be clickable, also I wanted to display the url what I did what to setup a custom command my mixxing commands `xcolor` and `hyperref` packages:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\link}[1]{{\color{blue}\href{#1}{#1}}}
```

So using the snippet:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\link}[1]{{\color{blue}\href{#1}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Desktop APP}: \link{https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop}
    \item \textbf{Android APP}: \link{https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android}
    \item \textbf{iOS APP}: \link{https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-iOS}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I have the following result:

[image: Sample Result]

Comment: Why? Just change the urlcolor setting for hyperref, then you can just use `\url` no need for href

Comment: In case you want speficic or multiple url formats (eg. Red for important stuff to read blue for others) I think my approach is by far better.

Comment: Which confuses users. `{\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}\url{#1}} `, btw does `\href` hyphenate urls correctly?

Comment: It will work great until you have an URL with `#` or `%` or `_` or `&` or `$` or...

Comment: To make the link text customizable, you can use `\newcommand{\link}[2]{{\color{blue}\href{#1}{#2}}}`. Then you can do `\link{https://www.google.com}{Google}`.