# Changing formatting of URL in biblatex \footcite

Tags: biblatex, formatting, urls

I've switched from `bibtex` to `biblatex` due to having to use `\footcite` based on university's requirements for writing a report. It may be worth noting that I'm also very new to (La)TeX.

I'm only having issues with an extremely long URL which spans three lines in footnotes and seems to use different line-spacing than footnotes ordinarily use. What would be the easiest way to force `biblatex` to not switch font when printing URLs in `\footcite`? Or even better, how to make it just use italic?

I currently use `style=verbose-note`, and I do import `url` and `hyper ref`.

---

This is not an exact duplicate of the linked-to question, as I don't know how to edit the URLs generated by `biblatex`, and *only them*. I find the formatting of URLs basically acceptable, but in `biblatex`-generated footnotes, and somewhat even in the bibliography, they look hideous.

---

An attempt at a minimal working example (which may end up being neither minimal nor working).

**thetext.tex**

```
\documentclass[times, utf8]{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{slashdot:2004,
        title = {{XFree86} 4.4: List of Rejecting Distributors Grows},
        author = {Collins, B.},
        publisher = {Slashdot},
        month = {2},
        year = {2004},
        url = {http://yro.slashdot.org/story/04/02/18/131223/xfree86-44-list-of-rejecting-distributors-grows}
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[style=verbose-note,natbib=true,sortcites=true,defernumbers=true,pageref,block=space,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
Here is some text\footcite{slashdot:2004}.

\end{document}
```

**Makefile**

```
thetext.pdf: thetext.tex literature.bib
        pdflatex thetext.tex
        biber thetext
        pdflatex thetext.tex
```

In this example, the output even looks decent… unfortunately, the actual template I use (a modification of another university's template) has different margins, different font, etc. So in the actual PDF, the output looks less-than-decent.

My text:

[image: My text]

Example above:

[image: Example above]

Template used is called "tvz" and if someone wants to work with the actual template [it's available on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/ivucica/tvz-latex-templates). If someone needs it, I can make an extended example based on "tvz" available as well.

Comment: See Ulrike Fischer's answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/how-to-style-text-in-hyperref-url

Comment: +1 because the "original" question was missing the [tag:url] tag.

Comment: @lockstep Is this even a duplicate? I think you could read this question as “How can I change the formatting of `biblatex`’s URLs (while using `hyperref`) (but not any other URLs)”, whereas the other one is “How can I change the formatting of `hyperref`’s URLs”. Even if this might not be Ivan’s intention, it might make for an interesting answer? In that case, Ivan would most likely be helped at the other question indeed.

Comment: @doncherry Formatting inly `biblatex` URL really seems to be a different (though interesting) question.

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @egreg Added. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amend the definition of `\biburlsetup`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{slashdot:2004,
        title = {{XFree86} 4.4: List of Rejecting Distributors Grows},
        author = {Collins, B.},
        publisher = {Slashdot},
        month = {2},
        year = {2004},
        url = {http://yro.slashdot.org/story/04/02/18/131223/xfree86-44-list-of-rejecting-distributors-grows}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose-note]{biblatex}

\appto{\biburlsetup}{\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\normalfont\itshape}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Here is some text\footcite{slashdot:2004} plus an URL: \url{http://yro.slashdot.org}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's probably too much to say you're my hero over the last two days, but you're getting pretty close! Thanks!