# Biblatex italicizes @MISC entries

Tags: biblatex, italic

I made my bibliography using Biblatex:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

and it works fine except that all of the @MISC entries, which I use to cite websites, are all italicized. This would have been fine, except that the URLs cited are italicized as well, which looks horrible. Is there a simple way (package options?) to make Biblatex stop italicizing the entire entry?

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
Cite Book, \cite{Book}

Cite Misc, \cite{Misc}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The file `Bibliography.bib` contains:

```
@book{Book,
  author    = {Author},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  year      = {2014},
}

@misc{Misc,
  title = {``Title'' by Author (\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/})}
}
```

The above produces:

[image]

I would like the entire of citation [2] to be `\upshape`.

**Edit:**

Thanks to musicman's suggestion I managed to make the URLs print upright using:

```
\appto{\biburlsetup}{\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\upshape\ttfamily}}
```

But it still clashes with the rest of the bibliography @MISC entry, which is italicized. Is there a way to make the whole thing not italicized?

I have also tried

```
\appto{\bibfont}{\upshape}
```

and also

```
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\upshape}
```

But neither have any effect.

**Possible Solution:**

The crux of being able to make the URLs print upright seems to be the manipulation of `\UrlFont`:

```
\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\upshape\ttfamily}
```

However I cannot find `\UrlFont` inside the Biblatex documentation. Could there be a similar hidden command that controls the bibliography entry's font?

Comment: Take a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97682/46389

Comment: Thanks, that helped a bit; please see the edited question.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the document class and other relevant material so we can reproduce your described behaviour.

Comment: It would help a lot, if you could tell us which parts you don't want to be italic.

Comment: I've added an MWE and described which parts I don't want to be italicized.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why do you write all data in the field `title`?

> @misc{Misc,   title = {``Title'' by Author
>   (\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/})} }

Split it up like your other bib-entry:

```
@misc{something,
title = {Title},
author = {author},
url = {http://text.stackexchange.com}
}
```

Then you can format your title (quotes instead of italic) with:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
```

If you want to format the title for the @misc-type only, you write:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
```

Also consider to switch to biber-backend.

Answer (score 3):

You are misusing the bibfields for the `@Misc`.  Putting everything in `title` means that it gets italicised.  You should really be using `title`, `author` and `url`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
Cite Book, \cite{Book}

Cite Misc, \cite{Misc}

Cite Misc2, \cite{Misc2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with `Bibliography.bib`

```
@Book{Book,
  author =   {Author},
  title =    {Title},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2014
}

@Misc{Misc,
  title =    {Title},
  author =   {Author},
  url =      {http://tex.stackexchange.com/}
}

@Misc{Misc2,
  note =     {``Title'' by Author
                  (\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/})}
}
```

If you really want to force the formatting, you can use `note` instead of `title`, as in the `Misc2` example above, but I would not recommend that.