# fonts - \renewcommand for \href (text show in the PDF)

Tags: fonts, hyperref, urls

I am trying to `\renewcommand` the second argument of the `\href`command (`\href{URL}{text in the PDF pointing to the URL}`).

What I want to do is to display the text which points to the URL (URL passed as the first argument of the command) in italics.

A solution would be to wrap my text pointing to the URL in `\textit`, as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/how-to-style-text-in-hyperref-url), however, I am trying to renew the command such that I don't have to wrap the text in `\textit` every time I will insert a text pointing to an URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can patch the command with xpatch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\href{\begingroup}{\begingroup\itshape}{}{\fail}

\begin{document}
\href{http:~_bxx%}{sometext}

\end{document}
```

[image]