# How to style \href like \url

Tags: fonts, hyperref, url

I want to use the `\url` command but want to show a different text than the url itself. So I chose `\href`. The problem here is that the result is in a differnt font. Is there a way to syle the shown text of `\href` in the `\url` style?

Comment: Related: [How to style text in `hyperref` `\url`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79051/5764) (note the use of `\UrlFont`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\nolinkurl` inside the second argument of `\href`. Macro `\nolinkurl` behaves like `\url` but it does not add a link because this is already done by `\href`. Example:

```
\href{https://www.example.org/}{\nolinkurl{example.org}}
```