# Illegal parameter number in definition

Tags: macros

I found [a nice solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/how-to-style-text-in-hyperref-url) to edit the look of hyperlinks, but I have another problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\link}[1]{\href{#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

% error: Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa. ...tes/guides/collections/designfaq.html#a14}
\link{https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/designfaq.html#a14}
%   \href{https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/designfaq.html#a14}{Test}

\end{document}
```

Why does `\link{...}` not work? Exact the same url does work with `\href{...}{...}`.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: You have `\url` for this

Comment: You shouldn't put a full url in an argument. hyperref then no longer can do its catcode magic. There is a reason why the "nice" solution got only one upvote, and my answer got accepted.

Comment: If you replace the `#` in the URL by `\#` it works.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\url{https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/designfaq.html#a14}
\end{document}
```

But take care! Shorten your link or use `\href` with a good description, because such a long link makes the document looks bad.

Comment: I need a description, so I wanted to use something like `\newcommand{\link}[2]{\href{#1}{#2}}`, but the `\link` does not work at all.. But a direct call with the same URL and description works with `\href`. What's the reason for this?

Comment: @mrbela Well, description of https://tex.stackexchange.com, for example, should be TeX.SE or TeX.SX or TeX StackExchange, but not https://tex.stackexchange.com itself. It is not a description anymore

Comment: @mrbela So the syntax of `\link` would be the same as the syntax of `\href`. If you insist in having the thing named `\link`, you can "copy" the`\href`-macro via `\let\link=\href`. By the way: The reason why using the `\link`-macro does not work out as expected is: Both `\url` and `\href` change the category-code-régime (e.g., the catcode of `#`) before LaTeX reads their arguments from the .tex-input-file and tokenizes them. This change of category-code-régime is outmaneuvered  by having LaTeX read and tokenize the arguments for the `\link`-macro under unchanged category-code régime.